# Error in seq.int(from, to, length.out = n) : 'to' must be a finite number #81

Tags: r, phylogeny

I am attempting to plot a cophylo, and I get this error:
`Error in seq.int(from, to, length.out = n) : 'to' must be a finite number` and I get this plot:

Cophylo plot gone wrong

[image]

My code:
`plot(obj1,fsize=c(0.05,0.05), link.type="curved", lwd=c(0.2, 0.2))`

What is going on here?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Okay, I actually just realized that it's because of the edge lengths on the second tree. They're far too short. Is there anyway to adjust edge length in a cophylo object?