# How to make plot.cophylo ignore missing values (NA)?

Tags: r, phylogeny

I want to plot a cophylo object, but one of the branches has a missing value, and so the cophylo is not plotting correctly because of it.

How can I change the value or plot the trees without branch length?

Comment: Please provide some example data.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the example and the `cophylo()` function seems to handle missing data just well.

```r
    library(phytools)
    #> Loading required package: ape
    #> Loading required package: maps
    set.seed(12345)
    tr1<-pbtree(n=22,tip.label=c(1:22))
    tr2<-pbtree(n=10,tip.label=c(1:10))
    obj<-cophylo(tr1,tr2)
    #> Rotating nodes to optimize matching...
    #> Done.
    plot(obj)
```

[image]

**Edit**

The question was about missing branch lengths. This seems suspicious to me in the first place since it doesn't seem to make sense that a branch length is missing. However, the problem can be reproduced now. Maybe your NA's are actually the value 0?

```r
    # Now with missing value --> Indeed it doesn't plot
    tr1$edge.length[2] <- NA
    obj<-cophylo(tr1,tr2)
    #> Rotating nodes to optimize matching...
    #> Done.
    plot(obj)
```

[image]

```r
    # Replace NA value with 0? (I am not sure if this makes sense)
    tr1$edge.length[2] <- 0
    obj<-cophylo(tr1,tr2)
    #> Rotating nodes to optimize matching...
    #> Done.
    plot(obj)
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

The problem was with reading the Newick file. In particular, OP used characters in the names that are not allowed (e.g. ':').

<sup>Created on 2020-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The missing value is not the association. The missing value is a branch length value, so the tree is not plotting well

Comment: How can you have a missing branch length value? Do you mean a branch length of 0? Also, provide an example that showcases the problem.

Comment: I refer you to the question I asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64519227/error-in-seq-intfrom-to-length-out-n-to-must-be-a-finite-number-81?noredirect=1#comment114084423_64519227

Comment: I have edited the answer. However, a missing value in the branch length seems very suspicious to me.

Comment: Like I said in the answer, my only guess is that your NA values are actually the value 0. Maybe replace them and see if it makes any sense. But personally, I would go back to the tree building algorithm and see where things went wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. The problem still persists, even though I try to change the missing value like this: `x<-obj5[["trees"]][[2]]
x[x$edge.length==NA]<-0.0000001`  but nothing changes!

Comment: The Newick file itself does have branch lengths, but it one of them seem to come up as "NA" when reading into R

Comment: Okay. Then it is an import problem and not a problem with the `cophylo()` function. How did you import the file? It is very hard to actually help without the files/data.
Also, replace it like this: `x$edge.length[is.na(x$edge.length)] <-0.0000001`

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you! You solved my problem!!!

Comment: No worries, I have now updated the answer and it points to the problem (in case anybody else has a similar problem).